# Keyboard and Mouse sharing before login with OS X Yosemite

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, osx-yosemite, synergy

Are there any solutions available that would enable sharing a mouse and keyboard connected to a Windows machine (specifically Windows 10) with a Mac running OS X Yosemite before the Mac has been logged in? I have been trying to get Synergy to work for a while now, but it seems that (if I can even get it to run prior to login) it gives me error messages evidently resulting from lack of access to the window system ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603055/getting-a-mac-to-trust-an-application-synergy-on-loginwindow) post suggests that it may be a sort of bug in synergy, and I remember the synergy website once outright stated that starting before login was not supported). Are there any other options that would not suffer from the same issue, or is OS X Yosemite simply too locked down to allow this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that feature isn't supported with Synergy yet. However the team are looking for a way to implement it into the software. As you said, it's where OS X has additional security measures that prevent any application from running before login that makes this difficult.